# Swift umbrella header not updated anymore after setting it to another file

Tags: objective-c, xcode, swift

I have a project with multiple targets.

I've started to use Swift classes and added them to the project. The umbrella file `Target1-Swift.h` has been correctly generated and I was able to use Swift classes in my objective-C code.

However I needed to have a unique Swift umbrella header for all my four apps. Therefore I change this project setting:

```
Objective-C Generated Interface Header Name     --->    MyProject-Swift.h
```

It worked: still able to use the swift classes I've aded.

However new Swift classes are not anymore added to the header. So that it's not updated.

What should I do?
Ive also tried to clean the cache unsuccessfully with:

```
1) Close Xcode
2) Terminal -> rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/*
3) Terminal -> rm -rf ~/Library/Caches/com.apple.dt.Xcode
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that the new Swift classes were not inheriting from NSObject, and therefore were not visible in objective-C.

It wasn't a configuration issue.

Answer (score 1):

You should rather rename your "Product module name" field in build settings. So, then the new generated umbrella header file would be "NewModule-Swift.h"

You can see it from here, https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH10-ID138  in the section "Naming Product module"